# Configuring SmartTarget Triggers

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

I understand that SmartTarget 2014 (ST) Promotions apply to configured (templated) ST regions in selected Publications based on visitor **Triggers** (using a selected set of managed items) ([thanks, JanH](http://sharedbyjan.blogspot.com/2014/05/tridion-developer-summit.html)).

I have some questions on configuring or setting up these SmartTarget Triggers.

1. To use the automatically-added Segment and Contact Detail triggers require Audience Manager, right? In other words, to use similar Triggers *without* Audience Manager do we just need to add known visitor information to the ADF and configure appropriate Triggers?
2. Are [list of values](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-BE71C97B-F372-4B76-AD38-D56D2BD418E2) for Trigger Types (in `trigger-types.xml`) optional? 

   *Without* a list, I believe each Trigger Type automatically gets appropriate filters when setting up Promotions (*Start* and *End* for dates, *contains* for text, etc).
3. Are the Keywords mentioned in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-B80AEF9D-14A6-4661-936B-DEEF2B87AA3D) *Tridion* Keywords? And if so, is this the key name/title, description, or value?
4. To use the Keyword as part of search, I see we can pass a [Keyword](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-BAE22A45-3ED8-4717-800E-579DC05B821F). Is this only for (faceted SmartTarget) search?

```
<head runat="server">
     <script runat="server" language="c#">
       void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
       {
        Query query = Page.FindControl("elementId") as Query;
        if (query != null) 
         {
        query.SetSearchTerms("YourSearchTerm");
         }
       }
     </script>
</head>
```

A use case I'm considering is creating SmartTarget Promotions for specific pages and I'm not sure if using adding such a Keyword to a page would be a reasonable approach (a hack) or if page-specific Regions would be more practical.

*Perhaps non-targetted page-specific presentations should just be added to the pages.* :-)

**Edit**: I believe the basic functionality is the same in older SmartTarget versions, but the Promotion setup would be done in the Business Manager rather than from the Targeting section of the Slide-out Navigation menu.

Comment: hey alvin is this for 2014 or older versions?

Comment: Good question, it's 2014--I'm working with the Promotion setup in the 2013 SP1 Targeting interface rather than the Business Manager. I'll note this in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good questions, let me answer in 6 parts.

**1) Audience manager claims**

According to the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0345CD4E-7934-46EE-9A41-312B0BB4B7C4) (login required) Audience Manager provides claims for segments and contact details, like

- taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:segments
- taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:enabled

If you are not using audience manager you could have your own code populating those claims, and use the OOTB triggers in SDL SmartTarget / SDL Fredhopper. However I feel that this would be ambiguous, your code would be pretending to do something with Audience Manager, and maybe the data available in your system would not have the same meaning as Adience Manager.

Better would be to implement your own claims, so define a set of relevant claims, like taf:claim:customername:segments and taf:claim:customername:contact:subscribed.
Do the following to implement your custom claims, this is documented in the SDL Tridion core documentation and SDL SmartTarget documentation.

- define the claim uris, just think of logic name, you will use them in the next steps
- write a cartridge which defines the claims and populates them
- in some exception cases: populate the claims in webapp code instead of populating them in the cartridge
- add the cartridge to the web application and register it in cd_ambient_conf.xml
- tell SmartTarget to use the claims as trigger types by adding the taf:claim:customername:contact "path" to the webapp's smartarget_conf.xml
- add the related triggers in the trigger-types.xml in SDL Fredhopper
- enable XPM Footprint set by adding the claim to TRIDION_HOME\web\WebUI\Models\SiteEdit\Configuration and TRIDION_HOME\web\WebUI\Editors\SiteEdit\Configuration in the Tridion CME
- tell the webapp to allow XPM to set the claim by adding the claims in the globally accept list in cd_ambient_conf.xml

Check the manual for each of the configuration points above to learn where to find this configuration and for which services to restart/reload.

It's as easy as that, with these steps you use the supported mechanism to implement your own triggers, with full XPM integration, just like any of the OOTB triggers.

**2) Values for trigger types**

The list of values for Trigger types is optional. Add it and you will get to select those pre defined values when editing a promotion, leave it out and you will get a text box instead.

**3) Keywords in model config**

These are Tridion keywords. Mind that this config file is from the Tridion CME. I think this is the keyword value as the value property of a keyword is unique in a category.

**4) Search**

This is for SmartTarget search. Faceted navigation is another thing.

**Use case)**

To target specific pages you could do a couple of things

- Set up different regions, this works for i.e. the home page, search page, all product pages, etc. So for a limited list of regions.
- To allow users to target specific pages in a promotion you could use a trigger instead, like you mentioned you can use keyword triggers for this, you could tag pages and set the page's keyword in a trigger.
- Or just use a trigger with matches on part of the URL, for example the promotion applies for URLs which start with "products\new-arrivals".
- For another level of flexibility, let the editor put a region on a page with a component presentation. The CP can add the region on the page. The list of regions would still be limited as regions have to be defined in SmartTarget configuration.

**Older versions)**

Indeed in previous versions editors would create and edit promotions in the SDL Fredhopper Business Manager (the Fredhopper GUI). In SmartTarget 2014 the promotions are managed in the Targeting slide-out menu.

In SmartTarget 2014 the setup of regions is easier, it moved form the SDL Fredhopper configuration to smarttarget_conf.xml

**p.s.**
"Non-targetted page-specific presentations" are sometimes called component presentations embedded on a page ;)

Comment: To add to Jan's excellent answer: 2014 SP1 of SmartTarget will introduce a specific Page scope (internally implemented as a trigger). So your use case will be trivial when SP1 comes out in a month or two.

Comment: +1 for the explanation and insights, Jan. I see where business and visitor requirements fit with the SmartTarget setup. I like how Taxonomy is especially useful and I'll have to follow up with some ST content modeling posts. The URL for trigger options is definitely useful for (non-Tridion) business users and I'll keep the page scope option in mind. Thanks!

Comment: ST content modeling posts would be very welcome Alvin. Please add some screenshots, this QA is pretty tough for those readers who did not have the change to see SmartTarget yet.