# Click trail in ADF or SmartTarget triggers?

Tags: smarttarget

Jan Horsman clarified [SmartTarget triggers in this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/7577/46). How would we implement a trigger (for SmartTarget 2014) that "matches on part of the URL" for the current and/or past pages visited in a given session?

The use case would be: **based on a visitor's path through a site, promote this set of content.**

**Default ST Triggers?**

[By default](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-F167829F-C22A-4208-A8B1-7486325B0FF2), we have a trigger for `Session - Original Referrer`, but I believe that's the last URL (in the session) before visiting the delivery website, right? I might be reading the list wrong, but I don't see any default SmartTarget triggers for the current URL.

**ADF?**

The documentation for ADF claims, which SmartTarget relies on, describes:

> "Web server session-related server data—for example, session length,
>   click trail and so on..."

- For the *current* page, it looks like we have `REQUEST_FULL_URL` or `REQUEST_URI`
- Should we get previously visited pages (in the click trail) from one of the other [default ADF claims](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-66EDBEF0-FA3D-4B40-A8DB-7A2C7789C903) such as `SERVER_VARIABLES` or `SESSION_ATTRIBUTES`?

[Claims](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9AF4B158-7FAC-4538-9062-98A3395EC342)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the ADF specifically for this scenario, so you'd need to implement it yourself.

I would start by narrowing down what you actually *want* to pick in the Promotion editing screen. You probably do not want to have to enter the specific URLs that the user must have visited, right? Instead it should probably be a limited list of specific touch points such as Help Section, Homepage, Campaign Landing Page, etc.

Once you've figured out the options you want to expose in the Promotion editing screen, you should write a cartridge that exposes that information as triggers. It would need to track the visits to each section (based on the URL indeed) and add each one to the trigger value that is in the Query. So when the URL is the Campaign Landing Page, you 'check the mark' for that in the trigger so-to-speak. Once all values are in the trigger, the Promotion would fire.

Answer (score 1):

**Original referrer is a domain**

> We have a trigger for Session - Original Referrer, but I believe
>   that's the last URL (in the session) before visiting the delivery
>   website, right?

Kind of, it is the last *domain* before visiting the delivery website. The `Session - Original Referrer` is the external website which linked through to your website. So let's say you have a link coming from [sdltridionworld.com/community/developers/alvin-reyes.aspx](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/developers/alvin-reyes.aspx) to [createandbreak.net](http://www.createandbreak.net/), then the `Session - Original Referrer` in the [createandbreak.net](http://www.createandbreak.net/) site would be `sdltridionworld.com`.

**Original referrer is an OOTB trigger**

> I might be reading the list wrong, but I don't see any default
>   SmartTarget triggers for the current URL.

I think this trigger is available OOTB, see the screenshot below and the sc_refererdomain in the [OOTB trigger types configuration](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/28407548382b65b66eea).

[image: Original Referrer trigger in Tridion's Promotion editor]

**Click trail**

This click trail is mentioned in the [Tridion documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9AF4B158-7FAC-4538-9062-98A3395EC342).

I think previously visited pages, other than the Original Referrer domain, are not kept in the ADF session OOTB. You could implement a trigger which keep track of this. Maybe setting a flag when certain sections are visited would be most practical since that would easily translate in a *section XYZ visited* trigger.

Comment: Ok, I did find "Session - Original Referrer" as an OOTB trigger. I only mentioned it as the closest thing to a url I could find. I should have emphasized that I did find `Original Referrer` but nothing like `Session - Current Url`, `Current Page`, or similar. :-)